# Is the word to arbitrate too formal for daily life

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know is the verb to arbitrate used only in very formal situations (related to law)?

If so, which word can we use for more casual situations like scenarios below.

> Situation 1: In a semi-formal meeting with workers from the same
>   company. In a case possible dispute between colleagues, does another
>   colleague *mediate* or *arbitrate*?
>
> Situation 2: A trivial dispute between neighbors because of dogs, or a quarrel between friends at a school
>
> Situation 3: In a bar brawl. I think it would sound funny if somebody
>   says "I tried to arbitrate the brawlers/fighters but they kept on."

Comment: Edited. Murat, please [read this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4862).

Answer (score 5):

*Arbitrate* and *mediate* mean two different things.

A mediator is a person who manages a dispute and attempts to bring the parties to an agreement. A mediator is thus a sort of diplomat. We speak either *mediating* a dispute or *mediating in* a dispute or *mediating between* the parties.

- *Mediate* is a little formal, but not very. You might also speak less formally of 'acting as peacemaker' between the parties, or 'getting the parties to agree'.

An arbitrator is a person who is given the power to *decide* how the dispute shall be resolved. An arbitrator is thus a sort of judge; the precise terms of the arbitrator's powers are set by law or by prior contract between the parties. We speak of *arbitrating* a dispute.

- *Arbitrate* is inherently formal, since arbitrators derive their judicial powers from some sort of formal agreement.  You might speak less formally of *judging* the dispute or *deciding between* the parties.

It would not be improper to speak of 'mediating' between the opponents in a brawl (supposing you can separate them), but you cannot arbitrate such a quarrel unless you have some means of compelling the parties to accept your decision.

Comment: Thank you for your comprensive  answer.How can I say properly " if somebody .........(separate ) them, they would have hurt each other  badly."

Comment: @Murat "If someone hadn't separated them they would have hurt each other badly."

Comment: Is there any word connote separate + talking with opponents on what to do next

Comment: can we say " the old man reconcile the fighting men"

Comment: @Murat *Reconcile* means 'made them friends again'. But if they're actually physically fighting he's gonna hafta get them separated and calmed down first!

Comment: @Murat- I think the verb you might be looking for is *to break up*:  If somebody hadn't broken up the fight they would have hurt each other badly.  Another phrasal verb is *to step in* (intervene) which must happen before a fight can get broken up.   If he hadn't stepped in and broken up the fight...